# NAudio Воспроизведение mp3 во время его загрузки из сети

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, аудио, naudio

Как воспроизвести файл из сети по мере его загрузки? То есть, не ждать его полной загрузки, а уже воспроизвести загруженную часть, а даже с учетом, чтобы загрузку начать с определенного места, например со второй минуты, при этом не загружать все, что было до этого места

Так, как это делается при воспроизведении видео из Youtube: загрузка началась, после загрузки определенного размера данных воспроизводить то, что есть, и так же начинать загрузку с нового места, где пользователь указал позицию на шкале

**UPDATE:** на данный момент удалось сделать следующее:

```
WebResponse response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse();

AsyncStreamCopier asc = new AsyncStreamCopier(input, output,()=>{

      output.Position = 0;


      using (WaveStream blockAlignedStream =
                   new BlockAlignReductionStream(
                       WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(
                           new Mp3FileReader(output))))
               {
                   using (WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
                   {
                       waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
                       waveOut.Play();
                       while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                       {
                           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                       }
                   }
               }

});
asc.Start();
```

//// и класс для асинхронной загрузки

```
public class AsyncStreamCopier
{

        private readonly Stream input;
        private readonly MemoryStream output;
        private Action onload;

        private byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        public AsyncStreamCopier(Stream input, MemoryStream output, Action onload)
        {
            this.input = input;
            this.output = output;
            this.onload= onload;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            GetNextChunk();
        }

        private void GetNextChunk()
        {
            input.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, InputReadComplete, null);
        }

        private void InputReadComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            int bytesRead = input.EndRead(ar);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {

                onload();

                return;
            }

            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            Debug.WriteLine(output.Length);
            GetNextChunk();
        }

}
```

Асинхронно загружается аудио в `MemoryStream` (не знаю почему, но с output типа `Stream` это не работает), далее следуя этому вопросу-ответу https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp

делаем преобразования стрима в воспроизводимый формат и воспроизводим.

Остался не мало важный шаг: воспроизводить это тогда, когда `MemoryStream` еще пополняется. Как это осуществить?

Comment: Ну, если есть потоковый декодер, он по идее будет выдавать поток аудиоданных по мере получения mp3.

Comment: [How to Play Streaming MP3 Using NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.ru/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html)

Comment: Пример кода?!??